# Enlarging a picture by adding pixels in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I was wondering is there a way(some code or functions) to convert an image with specific number of pixels into a picture with more pixels in matlab(enlarging the size or the number of the picture)?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! This question is basically an RTFM question, which is off topic for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox then you might want to use the [imresize](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) function. It allows you to choose various interpolation algorithms. Help is very clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use imread to get the image values, interp2 for the interpolation, and imwrite to make a new file.  Pay attention to data format and scaling.  Read the docs for these 3 functions and you should be ok

Comment: @jojek good point